# Laraven Cron Exression

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need to set the frequency of execution of a task judiciously with the start date of the same, could anyone help me?

For example, perform a task every 25 days starting on 12/15/2018

Answer (score 0):

You can place your code into app/console/kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')->monthlyOn(23);
}
```

Also if you need to run these tasks starting from specific date you can wrap it into conditional

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    if(Carbon::now() > Carbon::parse('12/15/2018')){
       $schedule->command('inspire')->monthlyOn(23);
    }
}
```

If you need to perform task every 25 days, you could make a db table where you log when the task was performed and add new record to this table every time you perform new task. Then You can set schedule to daily and before executing task check if the last task was performed 25 days ago.

Alternatively you can use Redis for such kind of persistence.